# Can I create scatterplots with "paired circles" in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

First, to clarify on the title. I am trying to create a single scatterplot. The nature of my data is such that there is 2 of each observation, and I would like each pair of observations to be "connected" in the scatterplot via a line or arrow between the two points.

To help with the question, here's a short dataset:

```
structure(list(evToRevJun15 = c(4.56, 1.35, 1.26, 5.99, 2.79, 
6.97, 4.9, 2.28, 1.26, 4.83, 2, 2.36, 4.91, 2.31, 2.47), evToGiJun15 = c(21.71, 
5, 4.85, 23.04, 21.46, 34.85, 44.53, 12.67, 9.69, 21.96, 11.76, 
19.67, 11.69, 6.42, 5.74), evToRevDec18 = c(1.99, 5.92, 2.13, 
6.6, 5.84, 4.32, 6.38, 6.77, 4.92, 2.67, 4.48, 6.69, 1.36, 3.79, 
2.41), evToGiDec18 = c(7.37, 24.67, 7.89, 34.74, 19.47, 15.43, 
33.58, 39.84, 28.94, 11.61, 17.23, 44.6, 7.56, 8.24, 5.74)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L))

> head(zed)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  evToRevJun15 evToGiJun15 evToRevDec18 evToGiDec18
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1         4.56       21.7          1.99        7.37
2         1.35        5            5.92       24.7 
3         1.26        4.85         2.13        7.89
4         5.99       23.0          6.6        34.7 
5         2.79       21.5          5.84       19.5 
6         6.97       34.8          4.32       15.4
```

The two `evToRev` columns are for the X-axis, and the two `evToGi` columns are for the Y-axis, and therefore each row in the dataframe constitutes two points in the graph.

[Here](https://fivethirtyeight.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/haxby-realpsg-0305.png?w=1150) is an example that *sort of* highlights what I'm going for, but not exactly. Imagine this graph, but instead of 5 points for Messi, there would be 2 points for Messi, 2 for Angel di Maria, 2 for Neymar, etc.

Any thoughts or help on this would be great! Please let me know if i can add additional clarification.

Edit: The 2nd and 3rd graphs in [this article](https://peltiertech.com/connect-two-xy-series-with-arrows/) are a better example of what im going for.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in achieving this is reshaping the data into a format that works better with ggplot - once you've done that, the actual plotting code is pretty simple:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_long = df %>%
    # Need an id that will keep observations together
    #   once they've been split into separate rows
    mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
    gather(key = "key", value = "value", -id) %>%
    mutate(Time = str_sub(key, nchar(key) - 4),
           Type = str_remove(key, Time)) %>%
    select(-key) %>%
    # In this case we don't want the data entirely
    #   'long' since evToRev and evToGi will be
    #   mapped separately to x and y
    spread(Type, value)

df_long %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=evToRev, y=evToGi, colour=Time)) +
    # group aesthetic controls which points are connected
    geom_line(aes(group = id), colour = "grey40") +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    theme_bw()
```

Result:

[image]

The reshaping could probably be done more neatly using `tidyr::pivot_longer()`,
but that's still only available in the dev version, so I've used `gather` and `spread`.

Comment: `geom_line` with the `group` aesthetic - thank you very much!